# How Do I Set Document Language in Word for Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, language

You can change the default language, but Word for Mac doesn’t seem to have a document setting, and it brings English (US) in from other docs when you import text and infects the whole thing.  Why no Document Language Set function? It is different than Windows for PC.